# Append CSS Style element from TextArea element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page with TextArea and label, I need to write CSS classes in the TextArea and use that by the label:

```
<textarea id="txtCSS" name="txtCSS" rows="4" cols="50">
    .FC{color:green;}
</textarea>

<label class="FC">Some Text</label>
```

How to do that.

Comment: You want a `<textarea>` element to accept CSS rules and apply those rules to the page? When you started to write your functionality how far did you get, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, whatever CSS classes written in the <textarea> to be applied to the page elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
const css = function() {
  const [_,clas,css] = document.getElementById("txtCSS").value.match(/\.(\w+){(.*)}/)
  document.querySelector("."+clas).style=css;
}
document.getElementById("txtCSS").addEventListener("input",css)
css()
```

```html
<textarea id="txtCSS" name="txtCSS" rows="4" cols="50">
    .FC{color:green;}
</textarea>

<label class="FC">Some Text</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the value of textarea into the `style` tag.

1. Watch the event `input` on textarea to collect the new content
2. Try to query `style` tag by id `previewStyle` if exist then we just only append text otherwise, we have to create a new `style` tag and append content into this one.

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ttquang1063750/aq4tfue3/40/)

```js
function render(value) {
  let previewStyle = document.getElementById('previewStyle');
  if(!previewStyle) {
    addStyle(value);
  }else {
    previewStyle.innerText = value; 
  }
}

function addStyle(styles) { 
  /* Create style document */ 
  const css = document.createElement('style'); 
  css.type = 'text/css'; 
  css.id = 'previewStyle'; 

  if (css.styleSheet){
   css.styleSheet.cssText = styles; 
  } else {
   css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles)); 
  } 

  /* Append style to the tag name */ 
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css); 
}

const text = document.getElementById('txtCSS');
text.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
 const content = e.target.value;
 render(content);
});

render(text.value);
```

Please consider using library replace with current textarea for some advanced code highlight such as:

- [tui-editor](https://ui.toast.com/tui-editor)
- [ace](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about)
- etc.